# multiple aggregations on same column using agg in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I am not able to get multiple metrics using agg as below.

```
table.select("date_time")\
    .withColumn("date",to_timestamp("date_time"))\
    .agg({'date_time':'max', 'date_time':'min'}).show()
```

[image]

I see that second aggregation overwriting first aggregation,
can someone help me to get multiple aggregations on same column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't replicate and make sure that it works but I would suggest instead of using a `dict` for your aggregations try it like this:

```
table.select("date_time")\
    .withColumn("date",to_timestamp("date_time"))\
    .agg(min('date_time'), max('date_time')).show()
```